# Getting logged out after refreshing page or restarting angular app, MSAL service

Tags: angular, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have integrated Azure Active Directory with MSAL in my angular application, So everything works fine until the page is refreshed.

I mean when I start my application, I go with the flow of Login, then I get user email and other details after completing the Login process but when I copy the URL and open in a new tab of the same browser I am logged out, I need to log in again.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your storage to localStorage. MSAL defaults to sessionStorage.

Comment: i tried using sessionStorage but that didn't worked

Comment: sessionStorage is only maintained for a single browser tab in a single session and will result in the behavior you are experiencing. Please try localStorage instead if you would like to maintain authenticated state across multiple browser tabs